# Double counts when left joining in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, left-join

I have the following tables:

**users** which have the following columns:

```
id: INT
name: VARCHAR
boss_id: INT
```

**bosses** which have the following columns:

```
id: INT
name: VARCHAR
```

**messages** which have the following columns:

```
author_id: INT (reference to users)
body: VARCHAR
type: VARCHAR
```

**messages_targets** which have the following columns:

```
user_id: INT (reference to users)
message_id: INT (reference to messages)
```

Now, I have the following query that is properly returning me **for each of the bosses, the percentage of users who have received at least one message of type 'urgent'** This is how I have done the query:

```
SELECT (COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN messages.type = 'urgent' THEN users.id END)::float / NULLIF(COUNT(DISTINCT users.id)::float, 0)) * 100,
bosses.id
FROM bosses
LEFT JOIN users ON users.boss_id = bosses.id
LEFT JOIN messages_targets ON messages_targets.user_id = users.id
LEFT JOIN messages ON messages.id = messages_targets.message_id
GROUP BY bosses.id
```

Now, I want to modify that query so that it also returns me, the count of urgent messages that the users have authored grouped by their boss. So, I have tried this:

```
SELECT (COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN messages.type = 'urgent' THEN users.id END)::float / NULLIF(COUNT(DISTINCT users.id)::float, 0)) * 100 as percentage_received,
COUNT(CASE WHEN authored_messages.type = 'urgent' THEN 1 END) authored_messages_count
bosses.id
FROM bosses
LEFT JOIN users ON users.boss_id = bosses.id
LEFT JOIN messages_targets ON messages_targets.user_id = users.id
LEFT JOIN messages ON messages.id = messages_targets.message_id
LEFT JOIN messages authored_messages ON messages.author_id = users.id
GROUP BY bosses.id
```

But this is not working. It seems is double counting some data.

Here is some sample data, and following on what I would expect:

```
bosses (id, name)
1, John
2, Charles

users (id, name, boss_id)
1, Mai, 1
2, Donald, 1
3, Denver, 2

messages (author_id, body, type)
1, 'message from Mai to Donald', 'urgent'
2, 'message from Donald to Denver', 'normal'
3, 'message from Denver to Mai', 'urgent'
4, 'message from Mai to Donald', 'urgent'

messages_targets (user_id, message_id)
2, 1
3, 2
1, 3 
2, 4
```

I would expect to get the following:

```
boss_id, percentage_received, authored_messages

1, 100, 2 # (Both Mai and Donald received urgent messages, and in total there were 2 urgent messages sent)
2, 0, 1 # (Denver did not receive any urgent messages, but he sent one message)
```

Comment: your sample data do not have a user with `id` 4. Moreover, the second query seems suspicious: `COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN messages.type = 'urgent' THEN 1) authored_messages`. It misses `END` and it does not use the new table `authored_messages `.

Comment: Sorry, updated.

Comment: Radim, I updated it as per the comments. Apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following query. It keeps the two aggregates separate so their joins should not influence each other

```
SELECT 
    (
        SELECT 
           COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN messages.type = 'urgent' THEN users.id END)::float / 
           NULLIF(COUNT(DISTINCT users.id)::float, 0)) * 100 
        FROM users
        JOIN messages_targets ON messages_targets.user_id = users.id
        JOIN messages ON messages.id = messages_targets.message_id
        WHERE users.boss_id = bosses.id
    ) percentage_received,
    (
        SELECT 
            COUNT(CASE WHEN messages.type = 'urgent' THEN 1 END) authored_messages_count
        FROM users
        JOIN messages_targets ON messages_targets.user_id = users.id
        JOIN messages ON messages.author_id = users.id
        WHERE users.boss_id = bosses.id
    ) authored_messages_count
    bosses.id
FROM bosses
```

Comment: Radim, where do I place the GROUP BY tho?

Comment: @HommerSmith there is no need for `GROUP BY` since you want the results per each boss in the `bosses` table